# Django dynamic model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to create budget app and struggling for creating dropdown lists (tables in database) based on each other in admin panel.

I want to created a entry model in which you need to choose subcategory based on category. tried with pirmary keys for all of objects of  category class but seems that it doesnt work.

```
class Category(models.Model):
    # category
    category_type = models.CharField(max_length=150)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category_type
class Category_Types(models.Model):
    parent_category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete='CASCADE')
    category_type = models.CharField(max_length=150)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.category_type

class Entry(models.Model):
    # single entry to budget database
    entry_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    transaction_date = models.DateField()
    try:
        for category in Category.objects.all():
            category_type = models.ForeignKey(category,on_delete='CASCADE')
    except:
        pass
```

I doesn't show me any possibilities for adding Entry in admin panel

Comment: Define things properly, you said `category` instead of `Category`, and btw, no need for a for loop :+1: just define the foreign key as you defined it `Category_Types`

Comment: I don't understand.Do you mean to create the category as attribute of ForeignKey of Category_Types model?  Could you please share some code example ?

Comment: In foreign key in `Entry` class, you said `category` instead of `Category`